# Get a list of all Discord.Member(s) that are currently looking at a given Discord.TextChannel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In Discord.py, TextChannel provides the property 'members' to "returns all members that can see this channel." (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.TextChannel.members).

I wonder if there is any way to get all members that **are currently seeing this channel**. In other words, to know the active tab/TextChannel of a given Member.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to do exactly that at all. What is your usecase? Perhaps there's another way of achieving what you want to do.

Comment: That's the answer I was expecting ^^'...
I'm working on an app where each Members have to write within a limited time in a specific TextChannel (1 Member per Channel).
What I was hoping to be able to do is to wait for each Member to go in the right Channel and start the timer when everybody is in place.
Currently, I'm asking to Members to call a cmd '/ready' and when all Members did it I start the timer. I don't know if there is a better solution.

Comment: The Discord API does not expose this information.

Comment: You could possibly start the timer when the users begin typing this can be checked, see the [on_raw_typing](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20on_raw_typing#discord.on_raw_typing) event